# Hsqldb do not write or save data to disk

Tags: file, save, hsqldb, disk

I'm using hsqldb-2.2.5. I've tried adding `shutdown=true` and `write_delay=false` to connection string. No success.

Connection string is `'jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:\\temp\\rvec;shutdown=true', 'sa', ''`

Code executed:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver @rawDataFactory.getDriver
@con = DriverManager.getConnection dburl, user, pwd
@con.setAutoCommit false

statement = @con.prepareStatement "INSERT INTO NODES(NAME, DESCR, DATA_HOLDER, SUBSYSTEMS) values(?, ?, ?, ?)"
statement.setString 1, ntf.name.to_s
statement.setString 2, ntf.descr
statement.setBytes 3, write_dump(ntf.data_holder)
statement.setString 4, write_array(ntf.subsystems)
statement.execute
statement.close
```

No data appear in log file or other database files on disk.
How to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering if `@con.setAutoCommit false` maybe you need a commit call.

Another idea: try sending a `SHUTDOWN` command to the DBMS.

Comment: Yes, without commit no data is written at all.

Comment: after SHUTDOWN, can i start again DB if yes how??